# 2-form written as sum of two simple 2-forms, only if the the 1-forms are linearly independent

Tags: differential-forms

Trying to prove that if $F=\alpha\wedge\beta+\sigma\wedge\tau$ then $\alpha,\beta,\sigma,\tau$ are linearly independent. $F$ is a $2$-form, $\alpha,\beta,\sigma,\tau$ are $1$-forms and $n=4$. Here is my attempt:

> Suppose $F=\alpha\wedge\beta+\sigma\wedge\tau$, with both $2$-forms. Then suppose for a contradiction that the $1$-forms $\alpha,\beta,\sigma,\tau$ are not linearly independent. Then it is easy to see that $\alpha\wedge\beta\wedge\sigma\wedge\tau=0$, by permuting elements as required. Now, $F\wedge F=2\alpha\wedge\beta\wedge\sigma\wedge\tau=0$, so since $F$ is a $2$-form we conclude $F$ is simple from part (a). But then $F=\gamma\wedge\epsilon=\alpha\wedge\beta+\sigma\wedge\tau$, which I think is a contradiction but I'm not sure.

I'm not sure if why I say it's a contradiction is the contradiction I'm supposed to get. What is wrong with $\gamma\wedge\epsilon=\alpha\wedge\beta+\sigma\wedge\tau$?

**Note:** (a) was just the proof that if $n=4$ and $F$ is a $2-form$ then $F\wedge F=0$ implies $F$ is simple/decomposable. i.e. $F=v\wedge w$, for two $1$-forms $v,w$.

Comment: Perhaps it would be helpful to include the statement of Part (a)?

Comment: Where is the uniqueness coming from?  It doesn't appear to be in the statement question.

Comment: I'm not sure. To be honest, I don't think uniqueness matters. But I'm struggling to see how this would give a contradiction otherwise. I've edited the problem to reflect these comments.

Comment: Depending on your definitions, one might want to assume that none of $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\sigma$, or $\tau$ is a zero form.

Comment: This is nonsense as it stands. Why can’t $F=0$, for example? You’ve omitted some essential information.

Comment: @TedShifrin The question verbatim from my text: If $\{x,y,z,w\}$ is the basis in which a $2$-form $F$ is written as the sum of two simple $2$-forms, prove that the associated one forms must be independent.

Comment: Surely they insert $F\wedge F\ne 0$ somewhere …

Comment: @TedShifrin Hi! Can we replace "this is nonsense" by "some hypothesis must be missing..."? :)

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the reasoning:

Assume both the $2$-forms in the sum are non-zero as a user commented. Now, wedge both sides of the final equality by $\beta$ from the right. We get $$\gamma\wedge\epsilon\wedge\beta=0+\sigma\wedge\tau\wedge\beta.$$ I believe this implies that $\gamma\wedge\epsilon=\sigma\wedge\tau$. But in this case $\alpha\wedge\beta=0$ contradicting the initial assumption.